# The Swedish Chef Translator

Tags: java, parsing, methods, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

So the context is, I have a CS project where input is taken in either word or sentence form, and then it is translated to what The Swedish Chef from The Muppets would say. I decided to take the input as one line of string, and send that line into a parser, which in turn would build an array out of translations of the input's letters. The conditions for what gets changed are defined within. the current error I am getting: (while using "INPUT" as input)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
    at SwedishTranslator.parseString(SwedishTranslator.java:62)
    at SwedishTranslator.main(SwedishTranslator.java:12)
```

Currently it is supposed to just print the array, I wanted to worry about formatting after the fact. 
The code:

Sorry for the walls of text but I can't find where the issue is exactly and I figured I would give it a shot here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to take a look at how to use the debugger to step through your program. Also the exception tells you exactly what line is causing the error.

Answer (score 4):

`ind<=in.length()` goes one step too far.

Use `ind < in.length()` or `ind <= in.length() - 1`

Answer (score 2):

The error arrises on line 62 which I assume is in your big if else section.

Within there you have several `ind++` calls. This increments the pointer you use in the loop. So if your code must go through several of these statements it will go beyond the array index.

Additionally you have an issue in the for loop as joval mentioned

**Edit**

The ++ unary operator increments the variable (-- decrements). Placing the ++ after the variable name (x++) will increment before evaluation, where ++x will increment after evaluation.

This is a common test question for CS students so I suggest you do some more research and practice regarding the operator.

Comment: So in.charAt(ind++) will actually add 1 to ind, and then when it checks the next condition it will eventually check out of bounds? I thought it was just checking one more than the count of ind.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a couple of really understandable beginner mistakes here. Instead of explicitly fixing your code, I'll tell you about a couple of things that, if considered while reviewing and editing your code, will also fix your problem.

The documentation for String.charAt http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int) throws an error when you attempt to access out-of-bounds items in the String. Make sure that you check that you're not attempting to look beyond the length of the String before you go calling charAt all willy-nilly! If you're currently "considering" the 'T' in "INPUT" and you go trying to look at the next two characters, Java will complain.

Second, and this is more of a general thing (though it does need to be fixed in your code above); the '++' operator doesn't do what you appear to think it actually does. When you do this: `in.charAt(ind++)=='H'`, you may think you're just checking on the value at the next index, but you're actually *advancing* the index at the same time! The '++' operator is very handy, but it has a side affect that trips up a lot of beginners: it assigns itself + 1 to itself! That means that if you're on the 'I' in "INPUT" and somewhere within your loop you call `ind++` once, you'll be on 'P' at the next iteration of your loop! When you see '++' remember that you're changing the value of the variable.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I haven't coded for about 3 months so I'm still shaking off a lot of rust in preparation for this next course. I appreciate the explanations.